# refer a html file and use their field in another html file

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jsp

`File name : old.html` 
    `Field id = "username"`
 
`File name : new.html`  
     `field id = "id"`
 
 
Now i want to collect `id` from `new.html` and want to send data to `old.html` file without changing `old.html`. What is the process ?

Comment: I think you should use  `Localstorage`.

Comment: You want to collect value that is saved with this `id`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

android has great javascript support for the webview as interface (java script object injection) easy to use. Catch values in local java environment and pass it next page.